# How to deploy only changed modules to pre production using Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a project which consist of 3 modules. I construct the project's svn like the following:

1. trunk
2. tags
3. branches

In the trunk, I have my modules + aggregator + parent like this

pom.xml - which is the aggregator
parent
module1
module2
module3

Using Jenkins and Publish Over SSH Plugin , I created a new job to deploy the application to the pre production server with the following steps:

1. Get the project from svn trunk.
2. Build the whole modules using maven.
3. Send generated war files to the production system using Publish Over SSH plugin
4. Send and execute a script file using Publish Over SSH plugin to deploy all modules to wildfly server.

And here comes the problem. Sometimes I changed only module1, but all modules get uploaded and deployed to the pre production.

What I want is to send only the changed modules and deploy them to pre prod, How can I achieve this to speed up deployment process?

Comment: Are you writing ant script for building module if yes ypu can check there?

Comment: Sorry for late reply due to problems I had with Internet. The answer is no, I am using maven plugin in Jenkins to build modules, the script I am using is a bash script to be run in the production to deploy war files. But I need is to deploy only war files that has been changed. @SanjitKumarMishra

Comment: maven command is (mvn --projects module1,module2,module3 clean package)